# Nginx 1.5.1 with spdy support, passenger and php

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, spdy

I can't figure out if spdy is already packaged with nginx 1.5.1 or I have te recompile it. I installed nginx with the following command passenger-install-nginx-module this installed nginx 1.4.1 without the spdy module compiled into it.

The php-fpm will just work on the nginx installation but passenger and spdy have to be compiled into the binary.

I hope anyone can point me to the right direction about how to compile nginx with both passenger and spdy support.

Answer (score 0):

Following multiple blogs about other versions of nginx I created the version I needed.

1. Stop previous nginx instances `service nginx stop`
2. Get the new nginx version `wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.1.tar.gz`
3. Untar the nginx source package `tar xvfz nginx-1.5.1.tar.gz` and `cd nginx-1.5.1/`
4. Check current nginx compile options `nginx -V`
5. Copy options to new line after you type `./configure {your-options}`
6. Add spdy option to it so my options are `./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --add-module=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/ext/nginx --with-http_spdy_module`
7. Create the install `make`
8. Install new nginx `make install`
9. Verify if nginx is installed `nginx -v` and has correct options `nginx -V`

This created a seamless overwrite installation of a new version for me.